# regular expression for MySQL always returns 1

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to fetch rows from my database by checking if the json in one of their fields contains a specific id.

`Example: col(kats): [2,4,7,9]`

I am trying to do so by using the following query

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '(\[|\,)1(\]|\,)'
```

The Problem: MySQL returns 1 for every row in the table.

Comment: what do you expect for response?

Comment: @miglio Some help? I explained what I want to do and how I try to do so. I am sure someone out there will be able to point out my mistake.

Comment: seem you forget the column to filter regex; your query should be like SELECT column FROM table WHERE TABLECOLUMN REGEXP '(\[|\,)1(\]|\,)'

Comment: Snap, thank you for the hint. Problem is: that is a mistake I made when writing this question, it is written like you suggested in my code.

Comment: @user3100343 I think `@miglio` meant: What do you expect your response to be, other than '1' as in what _should_ your code be returning?

Comment: Ah okay. Sorry for the misunderstanding! I want to get 0 as result for rows where '1' ist not in the stored JSON String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL requires that any literal backslash `\` characters (which are literal in the `REGEXP` string as escape characters to the following `[]`) be escaped themselves. Thus, you must double-escape `[]` as `\\[` and `\\]`.

[From the docs:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

> Because MySQL uses the C escape syntax in strings (for example, “\n” to represent the newline character), you must double any “\” that you use in your REGEXP strings.

The rest of your pattern is basically correct, except that the comma `,` does not require escaping.

#### 1 does not match:

```
> SELECT '[2,4,7,9]' REGEXP '(\\[|,)1(\\]|,)';
+--------------------------------------+
| '[2,4,7,9]' REGEXP '(\\[|,)1(\\]|,)' |
+--------------------------------------+
|                                    0 |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

#### But 2 does match

```
> SELECT '[2,4,7,9]' REGEXP '(\\[|,)2(\\]|,)';
+--------------------------------------+
| '[2,4,7,9]' REGEXP '(\\[|,)2(\\]|,)' |
+--------------------------------------+
|                                    1 |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```